# PetaPoco: Convert null value to empty String

Tags: oracle11g, petapoco

Is there a simple way to hook into PetaPoco and convert string properties returned as null to an empty string?
The DB I'm querying is Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

A getter method on the poco should work

Comment: Just wondering, why would a property getter not suit your requirements?

Comment: well, today all my properties are written like this: class Poco { public String Prop { get; set; } }.
I will have to rewrite all my pocos to use the more verbose syntax: class Poco { private String _Prop; public String Prop {get{...}}} which is inellegant imho.
Also it means that I will have to call the convertion function or the ?? operator in every getter of every String property of every poco. Which is also inellegant imho.
I'd rather do it one time in one place and keep my Pocos concise. :)

Comment: Makes sense. Never had to do this and not sure if it's possible but try implementing PetaPoco.IMapper and see what GetFromDbConverter() gives you